# Как сделать доступными базы MySQL в Perl?

Tags: perl, mysql

Использую Perl 5.14

В массиве. `DBI->available_drivers` нет записи MySQL.

Как сделать возможным использование БД mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

поставь [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) - MySQL driver for the Perl5 Database Interface

в linux это делается командой

```
cpan DBD::mysql
```

в windows с помощью ppm.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    BEGIN {
            use Exporter ();
            @ISA = "Exporter";
            @EXPORT =
            (

                $DBname, $DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword
            );
    }


    $DBname='dbdbdbdbdb';
    $DBhost='127.0.0.1';
    $DBuser='roger';
    $DBpassword='xxxxxx';

#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

 my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$DBname:$DBhost",$DBuser,$DBpassword, , { RaiseError => 1 }) || die($!);
     $dbh->do("SET NAMES UTF8");

лалала $$params{TMPL_VARS}{MENU}=$dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM menu where type=$$USER_INFO{type} ", {Slice=>{}});
```